# How to avoid that depreciation goes negative?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, finance

I am working on a project for my thesis, which has to do with the capitalization of Research & Development (R&D) expenses for a data set of companies that I have.

For those who are not familiar with financial terminology, I am trying to accumulate the values of each year's R&D expenses with the following ones by decaying its value (or "depreciating" it) every time period.

I was able to apply the following code to get the gist of the operation:

```
df['rd_capital'] = [(df['r&d_exp'].iloc[:i] * (1 - df['dep_rate'].iloc[:i]*np.arange(i)[::-1])).sum() for i in range(1,len(df)+1)]
```

However, there is a major flaw with this method, which is that it continues to take away the depreciation rate once the value has reached zero, therefore going into negative territory.

For example if we have Apple's R&D expenses for 5 years at a constant depreciation rate of 20%, the code above gives me the following result:

```
        year  r&d_exp  dep_rate  r&d_capital
0       1999    10       0.2          10   
1       2000    8        0.2          16 
2       2001    12       0.2        24.4 
3       2002    7        0.2        25.4 
4       2003    15       0.2          33 
5       2004     8       0.2        30.6
6       2005    11       0.2        29.6
```

However, the value for the year 2005 is incorrect as it should be 31.6!

If it was not clear, r&d_capital is retrieved the following way:

```
2000 = 10*(1-0.2) + 8

2001 = 10*(1-0.4) + 8*(1-0.2) + 12

2002 = 10*(1-0.6) + 8*(1-0.4) + 12*(1-0.2) + 7

2003 = 10*(1-0.8) + 8*(1-0.6) + 12*(1-0.4) + 7*(1-0.2) + 15
```

the key problem comes here as the code above does the following:

```
2004 = 10*(1-1) + 8*(1-0.8) + 12*(1-0.6) + 7*(1-0.4) + 15*(1-0.2) + 8

2005 = 10*(1-1.2) + 8*(1-1) + 12*(1-0.8) + 7*(1-0.6) + 15*(1-0.4) + 8*(0.2) + 11
```

Instead it should discard the values once the value reaches zero, just like this:

```
2004 = 8*(1-0.8) + 12*(1-0.6) + 7*(1-0.4) + 15*(1-0.2) + 8

2005 = 12*(1-0.8) + 7*(1-0.6) + 15*(1-0.4) + 8*(0.2) + 11
```

Thank you in advance for any help that you will give, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way would be to compute the residual part for each investment. The assumption is that there a finite and known number of years after which any investment is fully depreciated. Here I will use 6 years (5 would be enough but it demonstrates how to avoid negative depreciations):

```
# cumulated depreciation rates:
cum_rate = pd.DataFrame(index = df.index)
for i in range(2, 7):
    cum_rate['cum_rate' + str(i)] = df['dep_rate'].rolling(i).sum().shift(1 - i)
cum_rate['cum_rate1'] = df['dep_rate']
cum_rate[cum_rate > 1] = 1        # avoid negative rates

# residual values
resid = pd.DataFrame(index = df.index)
for i in range(1, 7):
    resid['r' + str(i)] = (df['r&d_exp'] * (1 - cum_rate['cum_rate' + str(i)])
                           ).shift(i)

# compute the capital
df['r&d_capital'] = resid.apply('sum', axis=1) + df['r&d_exp']
```

It gives as expected:

```
   year  r&d_exp  dep_rate  r&d_capital
0  1999       10       0.2         10.0
1  2000        8       0.2         16.0
2  2001       12       0.2         24.4
3  2002        7       0.2         25.4
4  2003       15       0.2         33.0
5  2004        8       0.2         30.6
6  2005       11       0.2         31.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of the absolute depreciation and stop depreciating when the asset reaches value zero. Look at the following code:

```
>>> exp = [10, 8, 12, 7, 15, 8, 11]
>>> dep = [0.2*x for x in exp]
>>> cap = [0]*7
>>> for i in range(7):
...     x = exp[:i+1]
...     for j in range(i):
...             x[j] -=(i-j)*dep[j]
...             x[j] = max(x[j], 0)
...     cap[i] = sum(x)
... 
>>> cap
[10, 16.0, 24.4, 25.4, 33.0, 30.599999999999998, 31.6]
>>>
```

In the for loops I calculate for every year the remaining value of all assets (in variable x). When this reaches zero, I stop depreciating. That is what the statement x[j] = max(x[j], 0) does. The sum of the value of all assets is then stored in cap[i].